# PHP "ERROR! [2] ... Only arrays and Traversables can be unpacked" not reaching set_error_handler() callback

Tags: php, runtime-error

I am trying a set_error_handler() on this error to throw an exception but it seems not to work.I see no error code.
I am trying not to display it to the user.

```
if(!$this->checkBindParams($t, ...$p)){
            $this->errorHandle("mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables ", TRUE); 
        }
```

...

```
protected function errorHandle($message, $trigger = FALSE) {
    ...  
    if($trigger){
        trigger_error($message, E_USER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

...

```
set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
        if ((!$this->isFatal($errno)) && ($errno != E_USER_ERROR)) {                
            return false;
        }
        throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
    });
```

I see nothing in $errno in the set_error_handler() function. But ofcourse it is not supposed to enter errorHandle(). This is just code example. I expect it to reach the set_error_handler() callback some other way though.

Comment: fixed PHP has register_shutdown_function() callback called instead